# relaxing the assumptions of Euclid's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

By Euclid's lemma, if $n|ab$, and $n$ is relatively prime to $a$, then $n|b$. Is there anything to say if $gcd(n,a) > 1$? If, for example, we only have that $n\not|a$.

Comment: Is 'pgcd' the same as 'gdc'?

Comment: Oups.. yes, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show that $n \mid ab$ implies $\frac{n}{(n,a)} \mid b$. Here Euclid's lemma is the special case $(n,a) = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\rm a\mid b\mid c$ then we can divide, obtaining $\displaystyle\rm \frac{b}{a}\mid\frac{c}{a}$ as a divisibility relation of integers.

Thus,

$$\rm (a,n)\mid n\mid ab\implies \frac{n}{(a,n)}\mid \frac{a}{(a,n)}b\implies\frac{n}{(a,n)}\mid b$$

since $\displaystyle\rm \left(\frac{n}{(n,a)},\frac{a}{(n,a)}\right)=1$. (Here we abbreviate $\gcd$ without the prefix, as standard.)

Answer (score 2):

If $n\mid ab$, then $$\frac{n}{\gcd(n,a)} \mid b.$$

**Proof**: From $n\mid ab$, we get $$\frac{n}{\gcd(n,a)} \mid \frac{a}{\gcd{n,a}}\cdot b.$$ Now the claim follows from Euclid's Lemma, since $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,a)}$ and $\frac{a}{\gcd(n,a)}$ are coprime.

Comment: It's too bad I have to choose only one answer.. :( All three answers say pretty much the same thing. I just picked the first one. I upvoted all three answers.

Comment: For a different proof: $n \mid ab$ and $a \mid ab$, so $ab$ is divisible by the lcm, ie. $a\frac{n}{(n,a)} \mid ab$. Then dividing by $a$ gives $\frac{n}{(n,a)} \mid b$